# Why is there no "parameter" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

When choosing tags for the question: " [Is there a difference between the "maximum probability" and the "mode" of a parameter?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26580/is-there-a-difference-between-the-maximum-probability-and-the-mode-of-a-para) " I was surprised to find no "parameter" tag.

I hesitate to add an unwanted (or unuseful) tag.
 Is there a reason for the absence of a "parameter" tag, e.g. it is ambiguous? Would it make a valid synonym?

Comment: Hi David, I know this is a very old question, but I have been looking through [tag-synonyms] threads to see if some are still unresolved. Consider accepting whuber's answer if you think it resolved this issue. Cheers. By the way, by now there is [parameter] tag, it's a synonym of [parameterization] (and rarely used).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most sites avoid (or even overtly ban) tags that add no or almost no information, such as "statistics" here.  More than half our questions deal with a "parameter" either explicitly (more than 11% of them) or implicitly (because they involve a model, a distribution, something to be estimated, etc: another 40+%).  Please consider choosing a more descriptive tag such as [estimation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation) and/or [bayesian](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bayesian).

Comment: I removed the tag, but don't [tag:random-variable] and [tag:summary-statistic] have similar ubiquity?

Comment: Indeed this description could fits many (most?) of the tags to varying degrees

Comment: Parameter is simply the number, hence as a tag it is too general. Concerning your question, only tag bayesian should be left in my opinion.

Comment: @mpiktas I have retagged, adding the [tag:estimation] suggested by whuber and keeping the [tag:bayesian] and [tag:summary-statistic] tags - the later seems appropriate to me since two the question is about the equivalence of two summary statistics.

Comment: @Macro, what is the "this" to which you refer?

Comment: I noticed that we do have a 'parameter' tag. While considering what possible use that tag could have, I searched the meta site and found this thread but it also appears the 'parameter' tag hasn't been deleted. Was it meant to be? If not, why not? I'm confused, given the discussion here which seems to indicate that it would be deleted.

Comment: @Macro, I have merged [tag:parameter] with [tag:parameterization] and have cleaned up the (few) instances of "parameter".  Thanks for following up on this.